# Center and Right-Alignment of Figures

Tags: horizontal-alignment, subcaption

I want to center figure A and B while aligning figure C to the right (as a legend). I tried to to that through `\hspace{}` first, but I then I thought it might be possible through `\hfill` or `\hfil`. I struggle to implement that. Any hints on how to do that?

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{position=top, labelfont=bf}
\begin{document}
        \begin{figure}[htpb]
            \centering
            \hfil
            \subcaptionbox{A\label{fig:A}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}}        
            \subcaptionbox{B\label{B}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b}}
            \hfill
            \subcaptionbox*{}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-c}}
        \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Present output:
[image: Present output]
Desired output:
[image: Desired output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\hfill` takes precedence (as it were) over `\hfil`, so replacing `\hfil` by `\hfill` is enough to achieve the desired output:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{position=top, labelfont=bf}
\begin{document}
        \begin{figure}[htpb]
            \centering
            \hfill
            \subcaptionbox{A\label{fig:A}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}}        
            \subcaptionbox{B\label{B}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b}}
            \hfill
            \subcaptionbox*{}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-c}}
        \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

**EDIT:** to center A and B across the width of the whole page, rather than the space not occupied by C, you can use `\makebox` to put C into a zero-width box. Here's a comparison of both:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{position=top, labelfont=bf}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htpb]
        \centering
        \hfill
        \subcaptionbox{A\label{fig:A}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}}        
        \subcaptionbox{B\label{B}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b}}
        \hfill
        \subcaptionbox*{}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-c}}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}[htpb]
        \centering
        \hfill
        \subcaptionbox{A\label{fig:A}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}}        
        \subcaptionbox{B\label{B}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b}}
        \hfill
        \makebox[0pt][r]{\subcaptionbox*{}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-c}}}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

`\makebox` is used with two optional arguments here: the first specifies the width of the box (`0pt`), the second the alignment of the box's content (i.e. C) within the box (`r`, so that the right edge of C is where the box is). [latexref.xyz](https://latexref.xyz/_005cmbox-_0026-_005cmakebox.html#g_t_005cmbox-_0026-_005cmakebox) has more on `\makebox`.

Comment: It seems that this output aligns figure B in the center, but not both A and B. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: You're right, this centers A and B in the space that's not occupied by C. You can wrap C in a zero-width box; I'll amend my answer.